# IotEdge on K8s: createOptions to add Pod/Deployment annotations (e.g. dapr)

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We are using **iotedge on kubernetes** and I am looking for a way to add **dapr sidecars** to the deployed iothub modules.

Are there any other custom **createOptions** available to bypass the iothub abstraction?

To be more specific: In the Pod/Deployment manifests require special dapr annotations so that the Dapr Sidecar Injector can do its work.

```
  annotations:
    dapr.io/enabled: "true"
    dapr.io/app-id: "nodeapp"
    dapr.io/app-port: "3000"
    there would need to be some
```

- [dapr annotations - deployment example](https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/hello-kubernetes/deploy/node.yaml#L32-L35)
- [dapr annotations - documentation](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/hosting/kubernetes/kubernetes-annotations/)

Just a quick summary of possible createOptions that I have found:

```
"createOptions": {
   "Env": [
      "storageFolder=/storage"
   ],
    "HostConfig": {
      "PortBindings": {
        "5671/tcp": [{
          "HostPort": "5671"
        }],
        "8883/tcp": [{
          "HostPort": "8883"
        }],
        "443/tcp": [{
          "HostPort": "443"
        }]
      }
    },
    "Labels": {
        "cqTargetPort": "80",
        "cqTargetRoute": "machine-api",
        "skipMiddleware": "false"
   }
   "k8s-experimental": {
     "volumes": [{
       "volume": {
         "name": "pvcvol",
         "persistentVolumeClaim": {
           "claimName": "azurefile"
         }
       },
       "volumeMounts": [{
         "name": "pvcvol",
         "mountPath": "/storage"
       }]
     }]
   }
}
```

[iotedge on k8s](https://microsoft.github.io/iotedge-k8s-doc/examples/services_internal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createOptions.Labels` are [translated into pod annotations](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/edge-on-k8s-public-preview/kubernetes/doc/edge-deployment-to-k8s-translations.md#podtemplate). So you can put the required Dapr annotations as the module's labels:

> metadata
>
> name = Name will be the module name, sanitized to be a K8s identifier.
> namespace = The given namespace. labels = Default label set.
> annotations = The pod's metadata will have one fixed annotation:
> net.azure-devices.edge.original-moduleid = unsanitized module id from
> edge deployment specification. then **settings.createOptions.Labels will
> be added to the pod's annotations.**

There is no way to "opt-out" of injecting the iotedge proxy but it should be benign even if it is co-present with Dapr's injected sidecar. I've not tested this, so let us if it works for you!